# Inverted index in C# Generic Collections

Tags: c#, oop, generics, named-entity-recognition, inverted-index

(Sorry if the title is a complete red herring by the way)

**Background:**

I am developing a map of all of the tweets in the world in real-time using the Twitter Streaming API and ASP.NET SignalR. I am using the Tweetinvi C# Twitter library to asynchronously push tweets to the browser using SignalR. Everything is working as expected - see http://dev.wherelionsroam.co.uk to get an idea of it.

The next step of the development involves parsing each tweet's text data using the Stanford Natural Language Parsing library (http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml), in particular the Named Entity Recognizer (also called the CRFClassifier) so that I can extract meaningful metadata from each tweet (i.e. People, Places and Organisations mentioned). The desired result is that I will be able to determine People, Places and Organisations that lots of people are talking about (similar to the concept "Trending"), and broadcast them to all clients using SignalR. I am aware that the Twitter API has the `GET trends` methods, but that wouldn't be any fun would it?!

Here are the main classes in my app:

**Main classes:**

TweetModel.cs (holds all of the information regarding a tweet as broadcast to it from the Streaming API):

```
public class TweetModel
{
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public double Longitude { get; set; }
    public double Latitude { get; set; }
    public string ProfileUrl { get; set; }

    // This field is set later during Tokenization / Named Entity Recognition
    public List<NamedEntity> entities = new List<NamedEntity>();
}
```

The Abstract NamedEntity class:

```
public abstract class NamedEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Abstract modelling class for NER tagging - overridden by specific named entities. Used here so that all classes inherit from a single base class - polymorphic list
    /// </summary>
    protected string _name;
    public abstract string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The Person class, an example of a class that overrides the abstract NamedEntity class:

```
public class Person : NamedEntity
{
    public override string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
        }
    }
    public string entityType = "Person";
}
```

The TweetParser class:

```
 public class TweetParser
    {
        // Static List to hold all of tweets (and their entities) - tweets older than 20 minutes are cleared out
        public static List<TweetModel> tweets = new List<TweetModel>();
        public TweetParser(TweetModel tweet)
        {
            ProcessTweet(tweet);
            // Removed all of NER logic from this class
        }
}
```

**Explanation of the Named Entity Recognizer:**

The way that the NER recognition library works is that it classifies words in a sentence with a tag such as "PERSON" for 'Luis Suarez' or "PLACE" for "New York". This information is stored in the sub classes of the NamedEntity class, depending on what type of tag has been attributed to the word by the NER library (choice of `PERSON`, `LOCATION`, `ORGANISATION`)

**The problem:**

My question is, considering it is likely that there may be multiple versions of the term "Luis Suarez" coming in (i.e. Luis Suarez, Luis Suárez), which will both be defined in their own distinct NamedEntity instance (inside of the `List<NamedEntity>` instance, in turn inside of a `TweetModel` instance), what would be the best way of grouping matching instances of the term "Luis Suarez" together from all tweets whilst still preserving the `TweetModel` > `List<NamedEntity>` parent-child relationship. I have been informed that this is effectively an inverted index but I'm not sure how well informed this person was!

**Visualization of structure:**

[image]

I'm really sorry if this question is unclear; I can't really express it with much more brevity than this! For full src so far, please see https://github.com/adaam2/FinalUniProject

Comment: So you want a structure where Tweets contain Names and simultaneously one where Names contain Tweets? That does sound like a inverted index.   Your fuzzy comparison of strings is then a second requirement that admittedly complicates the first one.

Comment: @NathanCooper Effectively yes. In terms of fuzzy string matching, I am using a fuzzy matching library that returns the Levenshtein distance (returns a value of type double) to determine how many edits a string will need to be the same as another string. I was thinking that the arbitrary max value for the number of edits be 1 or 2 edits

Comment: What you want is a many to many relationship where TweetModel has many NamedEntities and NamedEntity is present in Many TweetModels.

Comment: @Pedro.The.Kid And how would I model this relationship in terms of classes and their containing Lists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- add `List<TweetModel>` property to your `NamedEntity`.

```
public abstract List<TweetModel> Tweets { get; set; }
```

2- guaranty that your Tokenization function always returns the same `NamedEntity` object for the same tag.

3- when you add a `NamedEntity` to the entities list also add the `TweetModel` to the list on the `NamedEntity`.

```
Person p = this is the result of the Tokenization;
entities.Add(p);
p.Tweets.Add(this);
```

Basically the only difficult part is to have the function that generates the Named entities return the same object when it finds the text 'Luis Suarez' and 'Luis Suárez' on different Tweets.

Comment: Ah I understand! Right I will have to try this out when I get home from work and see if it works!

Comment: This works great! Quick question.. surely the TweetModel > Named Entity > TweetModel etc relationship will recurse infinitely or am I mistaken?

Comment: @adaam yes it will be infinite but you only iterate one, but manually the user can go from one to other indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to compare the Person then you should be able to find a unique name to represent them.

For example all Luis Suarez, luis suarez, Suarez, L. Suárez all translate to "Suarez"
This si done by MyHashFunctionForPerson

Then use a hash table:

```
Dictionary<string,List<Person>> map = new Dictionary<string,List<Person>>();

List<Person> FindMatches(Person p)
{
  string h = MyHashFunctionForPerson(p);
  if (!map.ContainsKey(h))
    map[h] = new List<person();
  map[h].add(p);
  return map[h];
}
```

MyHashFunction could be an abstract function of NamedEntity.
You can also check in the direction of overriding Equals, GethashCode etc.

Usually you have a map where each Person has an index. 
In this case you do the reverse lookup, each index maps to a list of Person. Hence the "inverted" index name.